# Filtering an array of objects against items in second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of objects to return only the objects that match items in a second array and I can't seem to get it to work.

```
export const Config = [
    {
        labels: ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3'],
        title: 'Home',
        link: '/',
    },
    {
        labels: ['label_1'],
        title: 'One',
        link: '/one/',
    },
    {
        labels: ['label_2'],
        title: 'Two',
        link: '/two/',
    },
    {
        labels: ['label_3'],
        title: 'Three',
        link: '/Three/',
    },
]

const filters = [
    "label_1",
    "label_2"
]

const filterdLabels = config.filter(item => {
  return filters.forEach(filter => {
    return item.labels.includes(filter)
  }) 
})
```

This is my code, I would expect that filtered labels is an array of any objects that have the matching labels in the labels array.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What is your desired result? What is not as expected?

Answer (score 0):

`.forEach(...)` is not going to return anything, just `undefined`, that is a falsy value, so your filter will return empty.

I am guessing that what you want is as in the following:

```
const config = [
    {
        labels: ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3'],
        title: 'Home',
        link: '/',
    },
    {
        labels: ['label_1'],
        title: 'One',
        link: '/one/',
    },
    {
        labels: ['label_2'],
        title: 'Two',
        link: '/two/',
    },
    {
        labels: ['label_3'],
        title: 'Three',
        link: '/Three/',
    },
]

const filters = [
    "label_1",
    "label_2"
]

const filteredLabels = config.filter(item => {
  return filters.every(label => {
    return item.labels.includes(label)
  }) 
})
```

Then your result will match the first item in your config, i.e. `{labels: ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3'], title: 'Home', link: '/'}`, which is the only one that has both `'label_1'` and `'label_2'`. The result of the filter is an array with only that element.

Change `every` to `some` to accept any element with either `'label_1'` or `'label_2'` and not necessarily both (1st to 3rd elements will match in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```js
const config = [{labels: ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3'],title: 'Home',link: '/'},{labels: ['label_1'],title: 'One',link: '/one/'},{labels: ['label_2'],title: 'Two',link: '/two/'}, {labels: ['label_3'],title: 'Three',link: '/Three/'}];

const filters = ["label_1","label_2"];

const output = config.filter(
   ({labels}) => labels.some(label => filters.includes(label))
)
//If, and only if you want to remove labels that do not match!!!!
.map(
    ({labels,...rest}) => 
    ({labels:labels.filter(label => filters.includes(label)),...rest})
);

console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filterdLabels = config.filter(item => filters.includes(item.lables.toString()))
```

Because the labels are strings it'll be much easier to convert the array into one big long string, and only then check if it included

Comment: Please, avoid answering without any explanation and showing only code.